# zipping in-stream to a csv using ZipArchive, CsvHelper, and Azure Blobs leaves me with an empty archive C#

Tags: c#, stream, zip, azure-blob-storage, csvhelper

I am trying to upload the zipped the results of an sql query converted to a csv to a blob.

See my code below:

```
  //this doesn't work
  using (var sqlCommand = _dataPointService.OpenSqlConnectionForCsvQuery(device, start, end))
  using (var sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
  using (var blobWriteStream = appendBlobClient.OpenWrite(true))
  using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(blobWriteStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
  using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(zipArchive.CreateEntry(fileName + ".csv").Open()))
  using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
  { 
    var generator = new StreamCsvGenerator(device, start, end, showTemperatureInFahrenheit);

    generator.FeedHeader(csvWriter);

    {
      while (sqlDataReader.Read())
      {
        generator.FeedRow(csvWriter, sqlDataReader);
      }
    }

    streamWriter.Flush();
  }
```

I end up with the following empty archive in my blob:
[image: 0 filesize archive]

However if I don't bother with zipping, everything works out:

```
 //this works
  using (var sqlCommand = _dataPointService.OpenSqlConnectionForCsvQuery(device, start, end))
  using (var sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
  using (var blobWriteStream = appendBlobClient.OpenWrite(true))
  using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(blobWriteStream))
  using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
  {
    var generator = new StreamCsvGenerator(device, start, end, showTemperatureInFahrenheit);

    generator.FeedHeader(csvWriter);

    {
      while (sqlDataReader.Read())
      {
        generator.FeedRow(csvWriter, sqlDataReader);
      }
    }

    streamWriter.Flush();
  }
```

Here's what the result looks like:
[image]

Am I using the ZipArchive / ZipEntry streams incorrectly? How can I fix it?

Comment: You don't explicitly dispose the stream returned by `zipArchive.CreateEntry(fileName + ".csv").Open()`.  What if you do?

Comment: hi @dbc, I did the following in there: 
`zipEntryStream = zipArchive.CreateEntry(fileName + ".csv").Open();` 
and then when i'm done writing, after the flush I do: 
`zipEntryStream.Dispose();`. This still gives me the 0 KB, empty zip blob. I also tried doing a "using" statement for that zipEntryStream with the same results. `using (var zipEntryStream = zipArchive.CreateEntry(fileName + ".csv").Open())`

Comment: I'm making some progress. Adding `blobWriteStream.Flush();` at least gets me a non zero size file, but it is corrupted.

Comment: What is `StreamCsvGenerator`?  It's [not part of CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/search?q=StreamCsvGenerator), and a google search turns nothing up.  Also, can you reproduce the problem with a `FileStream` instead of a `blobWriteStream`?

Comment: It's just a class that does some csvWriter commands like writeRecord, writeComment, etc.

Comment: I figured it out by the way, my Azure.Storage.Blobs and Azure.Storage.Common packages were version 12.6.0 and 12.5.2. Once I updated them to latest (12.8.3 and 12.7.2 respectively) everything works as expected. I spent a terrible amount of time on this. Lesson learned!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was to update my Azure.Storage.Blobs package to latest.

I was on version 12.6.0. Once I updated to 12.8.3, everything worked fine.

Here's how my call looks for anyone coming across this in the future:

```
      var appendBlobClient = BlobStorage.CreateAppendBlobClient(blobName);
      
      using (var sqlCommand = _dataPointService.OpenSqlConnectionForCsvQuery(device, start, end))
      using (var sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
      using (var blobWriteStream = appendBlobClient.OpenWrite(true))
      using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(blobWriteStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
      using (var zipEntryStream = zipArchive.CreateEntry(fileName + ".csv").Open())
      using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(zipEntryStream))
      using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)))
      {
        // this class is a csvWriter helper
        var generator = new StreamCsvGenerator(device, start, end, showTemperatureInFahrenheit);

        generator.FeedHeader(csvWriter); // this writes some comments at the top of the csv file
        
        while (sqlDataReader.Read())
        {
          generator.FeedRow(csvWriter, sqlDataReader); // this writes records
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to tell ZipArchive to keep the `Stream` open so that you can write to it with `CsvHelper`

```cs
 using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(blobWriteStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
```

If that doesn't work, you may be able write to a `MemoryStream` first and then upload with your `appendBlobClient`. The first part works, I was able to write to a local file on my computer. I wasn't able to test the `appendBlobClient` part, since I'm not setup with an Azure account.

```cs
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var sqlCommand = _dataPointService.OpenSqlConnectionForCsvQuery(device, start, end))
    using (var sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
    using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(zipArchive.CreateEntry(fileName + ".csv").Open()))
    using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
    {
        var generator = new StreamCsvGenerator(device, start, end, showTemperatureInFahrenheit);

        generator.FeedHeader(csvWriter);

        {
            while (sqlDataReader.Read())
            {
                generator.FeedRow(csvWriter, sqlDataReader);
            }
        }

        streamWriter.Flush();
    }
    
    using (var blobWriteStream = appendBlobClient.OpenWrite(true))
    {
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        
        blobWriteStream.AppendBlock(memoryStream, memoryStream.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: the issue with this implementation is that I have to get everything into the memory stream before i can start writing it. One of my goals here is to do everything in the stream buffers to prevent an out of memory exception when handling a significant amount of data